# force same font size on every mobile device

Tags: android, iphone, css, windows-phone

I would like that my site works like the mobile page of facebook. It is independent what the screen resolution is, the navbar etc. are always the same size. How can I achieve this?

This is how I want it on all devices LG Optimus Black (480 x 800 pixel)

[image: This is how I want it on all devices LG Optimus Black (480 x 800 pixel)]

This is how it looks on my Lumia 920 (1280 x 768 pixel)

[image: This is how it looks on my Lumia 920 (1280 x 768 pixel)]

Comment: What did you try so far? What were the difficulties and outcome? Did you at least take a look on source code of Facebook's mobile page?

Comment: The fb mobile page CSS is very bad to see. I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15333364/1126393

Comment: I added some pictures which show what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Javascript for this. Here's a jQuery approach:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('body').addClass("mobile");
}
```

Then you can style appropriately, e.g:

```
.mobile div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS media queries will only get you as far as detecting screen size or orientation. There are some but compatibility is an issue.

Comment: I added some pictures how I want it to look like.