# How use CSS/HTML to display text with height, for example, 2mm on all devices with different screen resolutions and sizes?

Tags: html, css

I created the simple web page displaying just text "Hello, World!":

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>Hello, World!</p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

On desktop computers with different sizes it looks OK. For example, in Chrome - Settings - "Fonts and encoding" it's configured this way: Standard font: 16

But on Android phones of different screen sizes and resolutions the displayed text is to small - maybe the height is about 0.5mm. 
On Android phones - Chrome - Settings - Accessibility I selected font's size, for example, 120% and it the same text height is about 2mm.
Because of the selected font size on Accessibility I think "Hello, world!" text must be displayed with 2mm. It does not contain any formatting in HTML. But actually the text is displayed with height about 2mm.

Then I tried to add CSS file main.css:

```
body, p {
    font-size : 40px;
}
```

In this CSS I use font-size : 40px;

The resulting HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it's displayed OK on phones (2mm text height). But text height is huge on desktop browsers. I know that there are different size units in CSS like em, pt, cm and in.

My question is which is the best and simple CSS code must I use in order to get the text height about 2mm on all devices with different resolutions and sizes. I know that it's probably possible to dynamically get screen resolution and size using JavaScript and then calculate on fly the font-size and use it even in px. But maybe there is a simple solution for that. 
I am not adding about adaptive site design depending on device. I just need to display simple text on web page. But the text's height must be about 2mm on all devices for comfortable reading without any additional zooming.

Comment: Haven't you applied `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag to prevent mobile browsers from displaying scaled down version of desktop layout (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag for details)?

Comment: I have found some answers on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333272/html-keep-same-character-size-in-all-devices?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change font-size unit in css file: cm insted of px?

```
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

and in css file

```
.test {font-size: 0.2cm;}
```

try on
https://jsfiddle.net/gyw48zhL/

Comment: I thought about this solution. But on mobile devices (at least) it's needed to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> to make it working. Otherwise it will scale the page. So using just font-size in cm or mm will be work without added viewport.

Answer (score 0):

give `font-size : 2mm;` in the body and assign view port by `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`.it will display as 2mm in all the browsers including mobile devices.

```css
body, p {
    font-size : 2mm;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```